# android setting Orientation locked the orientation

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I need to play the embedded videos in webview in normal orientation(as the webview is, such as PORTRAIT or LANDSCAPE), and force into LANDSCAPE mode in fullscreen video.
So I did as the following steps:

1. change the Activity's config in manifest file to `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`.
2. in the WebView's WebChromeClient class,

   ```
       @Override
       public void onShowCustomView(View view, CustomViewCallback callback) {
           LogUtil.d(TAG, "onShowCustomView");

           super.onShowCustomView(view, callback);
           mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

               @Override
               public void run()
               {
                   Activity activity = getActivity();
                   if(activity == null){
                       return;
                   }
                   activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                   activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
               }

           });
       }

       @Override
       public void onHideCustomView()
       {
           super.onHideCustomView();
           mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

               @Override
               public void run()
               {
                   Activity activity = getActivity();
                   if(activity == null){
                       return;
                   }
                   activity.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                   activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);                        
               }

           });
       }
   ```

;;
After doing this, generally it works fine. But it has one fault: before playing the video in fullscreen, the activity/fragment can rotate according to the phone direction, but after i return from fullscreen(LANDSCAPE mode) to embedded(PORTRAIT mode), the activity/fragment never change its orientation. How can i handle this case? i just want to restore to the original state, not lock the orientation.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);` ?  It's not a perfect solution but works very handy in a pinch.  Also, `android:configChanges` can be pretty dangerous to use.

Comment: yes, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR is more appropriate :)  what does it mean by "dangerous"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line after you set the orientation

`setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);`

It isn't a perfect solution, but works pretty handy in a pinch.

`android:configChanges` can be pretty dangerous, as it prevents the OS from doing its normal clean-up and recreation of activities.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can control the screen orientation [programmatically](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/08/set-screen-orientation-programmatically.html).